# References for volume of hyperellipsoid

Tags: reference-request, ellipsoids

I am looking for a reference that I can use for calculating the volume of a high-dimensional ellipsoid.

Here is the ellipsoid equation:

$$ \mathcal{E}^n(r) = ({X}-\mu)^\text{T}{\Sigma}^{-1} ({X}-\mu) = r^2 $$

Comment: In what form is the ellipsoid given? If you know the lengths of the semi-axes, you can just rescale the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbf{R}^n$ (which is known) by their product.

Comment: Added the ellipsoid formula.

Comment: OK, so just diagonalize $\Sigma^{-1}$ (if it's not already diagonal), and you have the semi-axes.